# function does not load ajax data after a while

Tags: jquery, ajax

Code:

```
function load_messages(id, msg_id) {
            // change hidden field so we know who the message is going to
            $j('#send_to').attr('value', id);
            // clear the textarea
            $j('#msg_area').val('Enter your response here...');
            // clear the convo area and put in a loading image
            $j('#convo-inner').html('<div style = "padding: 30px 0px; text-align: center;"><button class = "btn btn-small btn-light-blue">Loading..</button></div>');

            // ajax
            $j.post("/ajax/load-interaction.php", { id: id, msg_id: msg_id },
                function(data) {
                    // return data
                    $j('#convo-inner').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                        $j('#convo-inner').html(data).fadeIn('fast');

                        // scroll down
                        var div = $j("#convo-inner");
                        div.animate({ scrollTop: div.prop("scrollHeight") - div.height() + 99999 }, 500);
                        $j('#response').show();

                        // reload members list for future reference and to remove new message icon

                    });
                }
            );
        }
```

Everything works as intended, until I return to the tab with this page in a browser ( ~5+ mins later), then it clears the convo area but does not load the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have session cookies on the server side? Perhaps the session timed out.

Consider adding a fail handler to print out some info about the issue:

```
$j.post('endpoint', {body}, function(data){}).fail(function() { console.log(arguments)});
```

Comment: Yes, there is a session for member_id but that does not timeout since other pages that depend on that session work fine in that tab.